# Where do I find information about the reasons behind decisions made by the W3C?

Tags: w3c

I use the `:contains()` selector extensively in Selenium tests. The W3C specification has removed it.

I want to understand why but could not find documentation that explains the reasoning behind this decision. Have looked at [W3org](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (the pseudo class was last present in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors) version) and searched google.

Where do I find information on reasons for such changes made to W3C specifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably find the reasoning on the W3C mailing lists:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Flists.w3.org%2F+css+contains

There's lots of discussions about it. According to [this post](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0724.html), among others, it might have something to do with performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

`:contains()` was removed because they came up with another idea.  CSS4 lets you [change the subject](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject) of an entire selector with `!`.

So if you want to find all tables in your document that contain a footer:

```
!table > tfoot { ... }
```

This will do the same lookup as if you'd used `table > tfoot`, but the actual elements affected will be the `table`s, not the `tfoot`s.

I don't know precisely why they made the change, but I can guess: it's way easier for me to read!  And because you can't nest it or combine it with `:not()` or other such atrocities, it's easy for browser vendors to implement efficiently.